# @ManyToMany Can't add inverse row to JoinTable self-reference table. org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a Person class with mapping. I want to add two kinds of relationships between person: friendship and followers. 
Friendship means that people have each other in the friend list. Follers have only one direction of contact.

```
@Entity
public class Person {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "PERSON_ID")
    @Getter
    @Setter
    private Long id;

    ...

    @Getter
    @Setter
    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "RELATIONSHIP",
            joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "PERSON_ID")},
            inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "FRIEND_ID")})
    private Set<Person> friends = new HashSet<>();

    @Getter
    @Setter
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "friends")
    private Set<Person> followers = new HashSet<>();
```

I'm trying to add a friend. I suppose that JoinTable "RELATIONSHIP" must contain row: [1,2] and [2,1]. I add tests row programmatically to the database.

```java
@Configuration
@Slf4j
public class LoadDatabase {

    @Bean
    CommandLineRunner initDatabase(PersonRepository repository) {
        return args -> {
            Person p1 = new Person("Test1",
                    "Test1",
                    "Test1",
                    new Date());
            Person p2 = nnew Person("Test2",
                    "Test2",
                    "Test2",
                    new Date());

            Person p3 = nnew Person("Test3",
                    "Test3",
                    "Test3",
                    new Date());

            Person p4 = new Person("Test4",
                    "Test4",
                    "Test4",
                    new Date());

            log.info("Preloading " + repository.save(p1));
            log.info("Preloading " + repository.save(p2));
            log.info("Preloading " + repository.save(p3));
            log.info("Preloading " + repository.save(p4));

            p1.getFriends().add(p2);
            p1.getFriends().add(p3);
            log.info("Update " + repository.save(p1));

            p2.getFriends().add(p4);
            p2.getFriends().add(p1);

            log.info("Update " + repository.save(p2));
        };
    }
}
```

, but I have error then I'm trying to save p2:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint ["PUBLIC.PRIMARY_KEY_7 ON PUBLIC.RELATIONSHIP(PERSON_ID, FRIEND_ID) VALUES 2"; SQL statement:
insert into relationship (person_id, friend_id) values (?, ?) [23505-200]]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
```

I can't understand why this mapping doesn't work. How can I resolve it?

Comment: Without any further information my guess would be that one of the columns of the primary key is NULL (which is not allowed, hence ConstraintViolationException). Are `p1`, `p2` and `p3` new entities created in test or are these already persistent entities (with IDs assigned)?

Comment: @kamil-bęben I save previously all persons and after try to add a relationship between them. The primary key has existed for each person.